# Setting field visibility in ArcMap using C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, fields-attributes

I want to set certain fields of a featurelayer to be visible on startup. how would I go about changing the field visibility of certain fields?

```
if (featureLayer.Name == "LayerName")
{
    // Code to set certain fields to visible
}
```

I tried using the IFields

```
IFields fields = featClass.Fields;
IField field = null;
for (int i = 0; i < fields.FieldCount; i++)
{
    field = fields.get_Field(i);

    if (field.Name == "ObjectID")
        // field.Visible = false;
}
```

but I dont see a visibility property

**UPDATE:** Here is the equivalent code based on Hornbydd's answer below in C#

```
void SetFieldVis()
{
    // Get Document
    IMxDocument pMXD = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;

    // Get Map
    IMap pMap = ArcMap.Document.FocusMap;

    // Get first layer in TOC -> in my case set up an enum and loop through the layers
    UIDClass uid = new UIDClass();
    uid.Value = "{40A9E885-5533-11d0-98BE-00805F7CED21}";
    IEnumLayer enumLayers = map.get_Layers(uid, true);
    IFeatureLayer pFeatureLayer = enumLayers.Next() as IFeatureLayer;

    while (pFeatureLayer != null)
    {
        if (pFeatureLayer.Name == "LayerName")
        {
            // Get a pointer to the fields
            ILayerFields pLayerFields = featureLayer as ILayerFields;

            // Get the fourth field by it's index number and set its visibility to False
            pLayerFields.FieldInfo[3].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some VBA showing you how to change the visibility of a field for a layer loaded in ArcMap.

```vb
Public Sub SetFieldVis()
    ' Get Document
    Dim pMXD As IMxDocument
    Set pMXD = ThisDocument

    ' Get Map
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pMXD.FocusMap

    ' Get first layer in TOC
    Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
    Set pFeatureLayer = pMap.Layer(0)

    ' Get a pointer to the fields
    Dim pLayerFields As ILayerFields
    Set pLayerFields = pFeatureLayer

    ' Get the fourth field by it's index number and set its visibility to False
    Dim pFieldInfo As IFieldInfo3
    Set pFieldInfo = pLayerFields.FieldInfo(3)
    pFieldInfo.Visible = False

End Sub
```